# Strange transformation image Rectification Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I need to use image rectification of partially calibrated cameras, that is, only the intrinsic parameters are known.
So first I match some keypoints and use `findFundamentalMat(...)`.
Here are my results up to this point, seems ok?

[image: Keypoints looking fine]

The average error I got is : 274.326 (seems like a lot?)
the code I used to compute this value is the following:

```
vector<Point3f> linesL;
vector<Point3f> linesR;
computeCorrespondEpilines(pL, 1, f, linesL);
computeCorrespondEpilines(pR, 2, f, linesR);
double avgErr = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < linesL.size(); i++ ) {

    double err = fabs(pL[i].x*linesR[i].x +
    pL[i].y*linesR[i].y + linesR[i].z) +
    fabs(pR[i].x*linesL[i].x +
    pR[i].y*linesL[i].y + linesL[i].z);
    if(err != err)
        cout << "nan" << endl;
    cout << err << endl;
    avgErr += err;
}
cout << "avg err = " << avgErr/linesL.size() << endl;
```

This is the simple distance-formula for homogenous coordinates, right?
Then I basically did this:

```
Mat h1, h2;
Mat w;
stereoRectifyUncalibrated(pL, pR, f, imgL.size(), h1, h2);
warpPerspective(imgL, w, h1, imgL.size());
```

But when trying to display the image it looks like this:
[image: wrongful transformation]

So my question is: what am I doing wrong? Also I know that ransac is nondeterministic, but my average error is sometimes around the aforementioned 270, but sometimes it goes up to 3.79508e+19 and the like.

PS: pL and pR, are the matched points which were filtered using the mask from f, the treshold was 3. I know that there some threads about the subject around here, also I did follow the directions given there, my problem is just to find the source of the problem in the current situation.